# Twitter sign in with oAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth, access-token, twitter4j, sign

I'm trying to add the feature of sign in with Twitter to my website, but I just can't make it work. I'm using the twitter4j api. In the twitter4j site they have a sample code demonstrating precisely the sign in workflow. I tried to use this code but it doesn't work in one particular step (at least for me)!

I have a LoginServlet which is the one that redirects to the twitter validation page where the user grants access to my application. This is the doGet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    TwitterFactory twitterFac = new TwitterFactory();
    Twitter twitter = twitterFac.getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("<consumer_key>", "<consumer_secret>");

    request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);
    try {
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken("http://127.0.0.1:8080/AllMusicWeb/CallbackServlet");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
        response.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the twitter object and the request token are saved in the http packet (at least that's what I think those getSession.setAttribute methods do).

Then the twitter page redirects to a page of my application (CallbackServlet). All this is performed correctly.

Then the CallbackServlet has the following doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Twitter twitter = (Twitter) request.getSession().getAttribute("twitter");
    RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) request.getSession().getAttribute("requestToken");
    String verifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
    try {
        twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("requestToken");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
    response.sendRedirect("<other_page>");
}
```

The CallbackServlet tries to get the twitter and requestToken saved in the LoginServlet (using the method getSession().getAttribute()). This is where the problem is: the twitter object is always null!

I've followed the example precisely like they have in the code samples, so I was expecting it would work.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.